# How can I stop Symfony from loading from cache?

Tags: symfony, caching, composer-php

When I create a new project using:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton project ~4
```

Symfony automatically install everything like yarn, marker, webpack, profiler (loading from cache )

How can I stop Symfony from loading cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) that's using the caches files, disable it with `--no-cache`

```
composer --no-cache create-project symfony/website-skeleton project ~4
```